SNES sprites - are they rendered using shift registers or with a line buffer?
The SNES has the ability to render 34 sprite slices (8px wide) per line, based on up to 32 sprites from its 128 sprite attribute list. However something I've never been able to find a concrete answer to is how this is accomplished in hardware.
Does it work like the NES, by having a dedicated shift register for each slice that is then read out at the correct horizontal position to a priority circuit along with tile data to decide each pixel just as they are sent to the screen.
Or is it closer to some arcade hardware or the Atari 7800, having a buffer the width of the screen that the slices are drawn to as soon as they're loaded, after which the buffer is read one pixel at a time and combined with tile data as the beam passes across the screen.

According to this, it seems to use a line buffer of 2x 128x9.
I didn't follow the analysis myself, so just passing that on.
We have die shots and traces.
And here are even some details:

The PPU has a single linebuffer, but it is used for sprites only. (The linebuffer is actually composed of 2 128x9-bit linebuffers, each one storing 4 bits of color data, 3 bits for palette number, and 2 priority bits - one linebuffer stores the even-numbered pixels,the other stores the odd-numbered pixels. The linebuffers are clocked at 10.7 MHz when being written to, and have separate address lines; this arrangement means that 4 pixels can be written to the linebuffer every pixel clock.) It only needs 1 linebuffer, because memory access patterns dictate that it's impossible to render sprites while they're being displayed.
Backgrounds are generated via shift registers, just as in the NES. There are six pairs of 16-bit shift registers, coupled to six pairs of 8-bit temporary registers, labeled a, b, c, d, e, and f. There are also 4 BG attribute registers, each connected to a delay circuit that hold its previous two values, and 4 temporary BG name registers. There are also two tile offset control words, one vertical, one horizontal.
There are four types of BG reads - name table reads, tile data reads, and offset reads. On a name table read, the attribute bits (3 for palette, 1 for priority) are stored in the appropriate attribute register, and the tile index is stored in the appropriate name register. On a tile data read, the data is written to the appropriate temporary register n, with the low byte going into temporary n0 and the high byte into temporary n1. On an offset read, the data is written to one of the tile offset control words (in mode 4, bit 15 selects which control word to write to; in other modes, bit 15 is ignored); because offset reads come after attribute data reads, the first tile on each scanline is not affected by tile offset, and the offset read affects the next set of tiles.
Finally, of course, there are mode 7 data reads, which read 8-bit color data over the high bus and the tile name for the next pixel over the low bus, and increments the mode 7 horizontal accumulators. Theses are the only transfers that will put different addresses on the two VRAM address buses. Furthermore, mode 7 completely overrides the shift registers - instead, the color data byte is used directly as the BG1 color data, and in EXTBG mode, bits 3-0 are used as BG2 color data and bits 7-4 as BG2 attribute data.
The video mode selects which shift registers are used to generate each BG's color data, and determines the PPU's read sequence (the pattern of 8 VRAM reads the PPU performs for every rendered tile).
In 1 scanline, the PPU performs 33 BG read sequences (264 pixel clocks), waits 9 pixel clocks for the active scan period to end (because video output doesn't start until 17 pixel clocks after BG reading begins), and then loads 34 sprite tiles (68 pixel clocks).
The color data from each background layer is then combined with the current pixel from the sprite linebuffer (note that the linebuffer is erased as it is read) and fed into the priority circuit to determine what is actually drawn. The PPU's internal clock rate is actually 10.7 MHz (or half the master clock), meaning each pixel takes 2 PPU clocks. The first PPU cycle of each pixel generates the sub screen pixel, and the second cycle generates the main screen pixel. The output of the color math circuit is latched every PPU clock in H 512 mode, or every other PPU clock otherwise, and is then sent to the video encoder. Because the color math output is latched every PPU clock in H 512 mode, color math does not function as expected.

This information seems to predate the scans, no idea where it comes from, or if it is accurate...

Following the comment you had made earlier I found much the same thing. While the specifics don't seem to be reverse engineered there seems to be a consenus on that 256 pixel line buffer being used for the sprite layer. https://fabiensanglard.net/snes_ppus_how/
https://forums.nesdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=23927
https://fabiensanglard.net/snes_ppus_why/
